# PayPal modules for Node.js

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment-gateway

I need to implement some functionality which uses PayPal in my Node.js project. What is the available libraries for Node.js that supports PayPal?

Thanks,

Comment: A quick comment as this showed up first in my search via Google: PayPal released a [REST API for node](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs) in April 2013.  More details are at the [PayPal developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recall working on similar project and when browsing the web for troubleshooting ideas, I stumbled upon a thread that was useful for me at the time. I tried locating that thread, I think it's [this](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/44c19b52c7ebb5b6). Hope this works out for you, I remember it was one of those frustrating projects for me.
Dina

Answer (score 3):

[This article](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/integrating-paypal-express-checkout-your-nodejs-app) (and the [follow-up](https://www.x.com/node/4917)) by James Carr is a pretty good discussion. It makes use of his npm module, [paynode](https://github.com/jamescarr/paynode).

**EDIT:** The linked articles have disappeared (thanks for the tip-off, @UpTheCreek). But the module itself is still there and has [documentation](https://github.com/jamescarr/paynode/tree/master/docs).

Comment: Those articles appear to be missing.

Answer (score 2):

Available Now is PayPal's Node.js SDK for REST APIs , Very Easy [Here](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs)

```
 var paypal_sdk = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
paypal_sdk.configure({
  'host': 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
  'port': '',
  'client_id': '<Client ID>',
  'client_secret': '<Client Secret ID>'
});

var card_data = {
  "type": "visa",
  "number": "4417119669820331",
  "expire_month": "11",
  "expire_year": "2018",
  "cvv2": "123",
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shopper"
};

paypal_sdk.credit_card.create(card_data, function(error, credit_card){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  } else {
    console.log("Create Credit-Card Response");
    console.log(credit_card);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking for Node.js modules always check out the official [modules wiki page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules).

I could only find one Paypal module, the [Paypal IPN module](https://github.com/andzdroid/paypal-ipn) which can only verify IPN messages.

If you need anything more than that you will probably have to build it yourself.